# how create a table in hibernate ,that table does not exit in database

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

i got this Exception from hibernate please give me suggestions to solve this problem

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Hibernate: insert into PERSON1 (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, AGE, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at com.lara.Manager1.main(Manager1.java:23)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10656)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: The message explains it: `table or view does not exist`.  You probably don't have a table named `PERSON1`.

Answer (score 0):

The message is very clear if you notice

```
  Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Please check in your database name of table.I think it could be a spelling mistake.First try to run the command of inserting in your mysql or desired database as

```
insert into PERSON1 (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, AGE, ID) values ('ABC', 'XYZ', '18', 'id')
```

Comment: actually there is no table in database with PERSON1, but now i am trying to create a table with name of PERSON1.But it showing an exception org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammerException : Could not execute JDBC batch update